# Getting past entity framework BeginTransaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, testing, moq

I am trying to make sense of mocking in unit testing and to integrate the unit testing process to my project. So I have been walking thru several tutorials and refactoring my code to support mocking, anyway, I am unable to pass the tests, because the DB method I am trying to test is using a transaction, but when creating a transaction, I get

> The underlying provider failed on Open.

Without transaction everything works just fine.

The code I currently have is:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test1()
{
    var mockSet = GetDbMock();
    var mockContext = new Mock<DataContext>();
    mockContext.Setup(m => m.Repository).Returns(mockSet.Object);

    var service = new MyService(mockContext.Object);
    service.SaveRepository(GetRepositoryData().First());
    mockSet.Verify(m => m.Remove(It.IsAny<Repository>()), Times.Once());
    mockSet.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<Repository>()), Times.Once());
    mockContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges(), Times.Once());
}

// gets the DbSet mock with one existing item
private Mock<DbSet<Repository>> GetDbMock()
{
    var data = GetRepositoryData();
    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Repository>>();

    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Repository>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
    // skipped for brevity
    return mockSet;
}
```

Code under test:

```
private readonly DataContext _context;
public MyService(DataContext ctx)
{
    _context = ctx;
}

public void SaveRepositories(Repository repo)
{
    using (_context)
    {
        // Here the transaction creation fails
        using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            DeleteExistingEntries(repo.Id);
            AddRepositories(repo);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

I was trying to mock the transaction part as well:

```
var mockTransaction = new Mock<DbContextTransaction>();
mockContext.Setup(x => x.Database.BeginTransaction()).Returns(mockTransaction.Object);
```

but this is not working, failing with:

> Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: conn =>
>   conn.Database.BeginTransaction()

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the second error message says, Moq can't mock non-virtual methods or properties, so this approach won't work. I suggest using the [Adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to work around this. The idea is to create an *adapter* (a wrapper class that implements some interface) that interacts with the `DataContext`, and to perform all database activity through that interface. Then, you can mock the interface instead.

```
public interface IDataContext {
    DbSet<Repository> Repository { get; }
    DbContextTransaction BeginTransaction();
}

public class DataContextAdapter {
    private readonly DataContext _dataContext;

    public DataContextAdapter(DataContext dataContext) {
        _dataContext = dataContext;
    }

    public DbSet<Repository> Repository { get { return _dataContext.Repository; } }

    public DbContextTransaction BeginTransaction() {
        return _dataContext.Database.BeginTransaction();
    }
}
```

All of your code that previously used the `DataContext` directly should now use an `IDataContext`, which should be a `DataContextAdapter` when the program is running, but in a test, you can easily mock `IDataContext`. This should make the mocking way simpler too because you can design `IDataContext` and `DataContextAdapter` to hide some of the complexities of the actual `DataContext`.

Comment: This design pattern makes sense and I will pursue to understand it. Although I still can't get it to work as I can not mock the `DbContextTransaction` because it has only internal constructor, which seems to be a problem to `Moq`. Anyway, it apprears that the test execution does not really depend on it working and if I run the tests without debugging, they pass unless I explicitly check if any exceptions were thrown. Which is nice. Thanks for the insight, I will accept this unless something better arises. (y)

Comment: You can pull the same trick there - create an `IDbContextTransaction` interface that is implemented by `DbContextTransactionAdapter`, which wraps an actual `DbContextTransaction` - and mock `IDbContextTransaction` in your tests. It's a bit of hassle, but this trick will generally make code that uses library code much easier to test, and less tightly coupled to the library.

Comment: One thing thing recently surprised me when I did Mock.Of<MyContext> is that the Database property of the mock creates a concrete database object using the connection info in the app.config. So any Database.ExecuteSql would presumably run against that database. Also returned a concrete Transaction from BeginTransaction. How does that happen, that a mock returns a real thing?

Comment: Debugging the above it's obvious that the mocker must call the default constructor, which initialises the real DbContext. I should be using an interface anyway.

Comment: @RobKent: Good observation!

Answer (score 3):

I think you can mock the transaction quite easily by creating a derivative of `DatabaseFacade`:

```cs
var dbContextMock = new Mock<DbContext>();
dbContextMock
    .SetupGet(x => x.Database)
    .Returns(new MockDatabaseFacade(dbContextMock.Object));

[...]
private class MockDatabaseFacade : DatabaseFacade
{
    public MockDatabaseFacade(DbContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public override Task<IDbContextTransaction> BeginTransactionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) =>
        Task.FromResult(Mock.Of<IDbContextTransaction>());

}
```

edit: note, this code is for EF Core. Used with version 7.0 actually.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the wrapper/adapter approach, but came up against the problem that when you then go to test the code:

```cs
using (var transaction = _myAdaptor.BeginTransaction())
```

Your mock/fake still needs to return something so the line `transaction.Commit();`
can still execute.

Normally I'd set the fake of my adapter to return an interface from `BeginTransaction()` at that point (so I can fake that returned object too), but the `DbContextTransaction` returned by `BeginTransaction()` only implements `IDisposable` so there was no interface that could give me access to the `Rollback` and `Commit` methods of `DbContextTransaction`.

Furthermore, `DbContextTransaction` has no public constructor, so I couldn't just new up an instance of it to return either (and even if I could, it wouldn't be ideal as I couldn't then check for calls to commit or rollback the transaction).

So, in the end I took a slightly different approach and created a separate class altogether to manage the transaction:

```cs
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;

public interface IEfTransactionService
{
    IManagedEfTransaction GetManagedEfTransaction();
}

public class EfTransactionService : IEfTransactionService
{
    private readonly IFMDContext _context;

    public EfTransactionService(IFMDContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IManagedEfTransaction GetManagedEfTransaction()
    {
        return new ManagedEfTransaction(_context);
    }
}

public interface IManagedEfTransaction : IDisposable
{
    DbContextTransaction BeginEfTransaction();
    void CommitEfTransaction();
    void RollbackEfTransaction();
}

public class ManagedEfTransaction : IManagedEfTransaction
{
    private readonly IDataContext  _context;
    private DbContextTransaction _transaction;

    public ManagedEfTransaction(IDataContext  context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Not returning the transaction here because we want to avoid any
    /// external references to it stopping it from being disposed by
    /// the using statement
    /// </summary>
    public void BeginEfTransaction()
    {
        _transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public void CommitEfTransaction()
    {
        if (_transaction == null) throw new Exception("No transaction");

        _transaction.Commit();
        _transaction = null;
    }

    public void RollbackEfTransaction()
    {
        if (_transaction == null) throw new Exception("No transaction");

        _transaction.Rollback();
        _transaction = null;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // free managed resources
            if (_transaction != null)
            {
                _transaction.Dispose();
                _transaction = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then inject that service class into whatever classes need to use a transaction.  For example, using the code from the original question:

```cs
private readonly DataContext _context;
private readonly IEfTransactionManager _transactionManager;

public MyService(DataContext ctx, IEfTransactionManager transactionManager)
{
    _context = ctx;
    _transactionManager = transactionManager;
}

public void SaveRepositories(Repository repo)
{
    using (_context)
    {
        // Here the transaction creation fails
        using (var managedEfTransaction = _transactionManager.GetManagedEfTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                managedEfTransaction.BeginEfTransaction();

                DeleteExistingEntries(repo.Id);
                AddRepositories(repo);
                _context.SaveChanges();

                managedEfTransaction.CommitEfTransaction();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                managedEfTransaction.RollbackEfTransaction();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find a pretty good solution [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1138629/Mocking-EF-DbContext-and-DbContextTransaction-with).

In short, you need to create proxy class for `DbContextTransaction` and use it instead of an original one. So that you can mock your proxy and test your method with `BeginTransaction()`.

PS. In article which I linked above, author forgot about the `virtual` keyword for `BeginTransaction()` method placed in dbContext class:

```
// <summary>
/// When we call begin transaction. Our proxy creates new Database.BeginTransaction and gives DbContextTransaction's control to proxy.
/// We do this for unit test.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Proxy which controls DbContextTransaction(Ef transaction class)</returns>
public virtual IDbContextTransactionProxy BeginTransaction()
{
   return new DbContextTransactionProxy(this);
}
```