# C# unit testing MoQ, Mock DB context, issue when transactions are used

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I need to write unit testing for legacy code. I'm using MoQ for wring DB Context based unit testing.  One repository method contains saving 2 entities in a transaction.

And when the test execution hit the dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction() it gives the error "No connection string named 'LimaV3DbContext' could be found in the application config file".

It seems the test trying the execute the actual db context rather than using the mock db context. Is there a way to force the test execution to use the mock db context used in the test initialization.

I've setup the tests based on the following article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking

Comment: Is it possible to share some of the testing code? Particularly the moq setup of your connection context?

Comment: You will need to specifically mock the database object on the dbContext as well as the the method `BeginTransaction` on that mocked database object. So there will be some extra setup needed. Also - if you think that you are calling an actual dbContext instead of a mocked object -> It might be that there is a problem in your setup code itself for the specific tests.

Comment: Hi Terrance, I've done exactly same as in the article provided.   var mockDbContext = new Mock<DbContext>(null);
            mockDbContext.Setup(x => x.UserAccounts).Returns(mockAccounts);
            mockDbContext.Setup(x => x.Contacts).Returns(mockContacts);

Comment: So that leads me to believe that you will need to do something like `mockDbContext.Setup(x => x.Database).Returns(databaseMock);`. Where databaseMock should also be instantiated like: `var databaseMock = new Mock<>`.

Comment: Although I am not sure if that type will lend itself to being mocked. Lets hope :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32554434/3927043 I hope this helps you. Let me know if you need more clarification on this